# Apple pay with stripe : Using apple pay certificate not able build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, stripe-payments, applepay

I have posted this from last week . This post show you detailed descrption of problem.

I have created app with credit card payment using apple pay. It works fine with my Xcode.

What I want: 
My client have apple developer account and he wants to build app using his certificates

**What I have from client :**

1) IOS developer certificate

2) Apple pay certificate that is merchant id

3) P12 certificate

**What I have did**

I have imported above certificate in keychain you can see on this image

[![
Here is a key chain screen shot not: green one is of my client and red is of mine][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk6uv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk6uv.png)

Set bundle id of client in [image: here]

I have changed in my Xcode "Build settings -> code signing" with clients developer certificate.

**Problem is [image: here]**

I can't add merchant id that is given by my client.
When I click on apple pay/ fix issue/ refresh button -> Xcode redirect me to choose apple developer account. and It shows only my account.

Is this enough? if not please tell me steps or any suggestion.

I have updated my question. My screen is now look like

[image: This screen appears when I click on add/refresh/fix issue.]

Comment: Is there any certificate missing/invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My client added me as admin in his apple developer account, So now my xcode have access to use his all certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Try transferring the certificates in a different way.

To export:

Go to Xcode->Preferences->Accounts, click the "Settings" icon (bottom left corner, next to the +-) and choose "export".

To import:

Same as the above, only this time choose "import".

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @Arik... Please confirm me . My client is going to export certificate from his Xcode. right?
And I will import it in my xcode

Comment: I have updated my question. Your answer worked but now asking to use password of my clients apple developer account